# what is the difference b/w len(tuple) and [-1]?

Tags: python, range, tuples

i am trying to make a function which return back a tuple containing the odd elements from a bigger tuple, but it keeps giving me an empty tuple.
when i use len(aTup) instead of -1 in the range() to get the last element i get the correct answer .so please any one help me with the concept here

```
    def oddTuples(aTup):
       newtup=()
       for i in range(0,-1,2):
         newtup +=(aTup[i],)
       return newtup
```

Comment: `range` doesn't use list slicing syntax.

Comment: `range(0, -1, 2)` is an empty range

Comment: Aside: try `def oddTuples(aTup): return aTup[0::2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> help(range)
Help on built-in function range in module __builtin__:

range(...)
    range(stop) -> list of integers
    range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers

    Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
    range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.
    When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
    For example, range(4) returns [0, 1, 2, 3].  The end point is omitted!
    These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
```

By default, range makes a list from start to stop (hence `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`). If start is greater than stop, the list will be empty. You can't use string/list slicing syntax.

Comment: Did you mean *"If start is greater than stop, the list will be empty."*? In that case: not if `step` is negative.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for catching that. With the default step of 1, of course.